# Get json object without JSON.parse?

Tags: json, jquery

I found this:

Use Python output:

```
print ‘Content-type: text/x-json\n\n’
print json.dumps([{'title':arr['title']}])
```

and get json string with Jquery:

```
$ajax(   
   success: function(msg){
      if(msg[0].title) alert(msg[0].title);
   }
)
```

It works, who can tell me why it is? Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery calls JSON.parse internally on modern browsers that have it if the Content-Type is json

```
        return window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ?
            window.JSON.parse( data ) :
            (new Function("return " + data))();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe jQuery is able to determine the response type based on the header you are sending and automatically evaluate it as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `dataType` to `"json"` or you *don't* set it and the `content-type` header contains the string `"json"`, it tries to parse it, [you can see the logic at work here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L684):

```
if ( typeof data === "string" ) {
  // Get the JavaScript object, if JSON is used.
  if ( type === "json" || !type && ct.indexOf("json") >= 0 ) {
    data = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

  // If the type is "script", eval it in global context
  } else if ( type === "script" || !type && ct.indexOf("javascript") >= 0 ) {
    jQuery.globalEval( data );
  }
}
```

If you're curious, the source for [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) is [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L532).